# How to import a huge 18 GB SQL file (that contains INSERT statements) into a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, file, import, insert, dump

I already have the schema/tables all created.

I don't have access to a `.bak` file, so this 18 GB SQL file is all I have. It contains all the data I need to restore the database. I generated this file using SSMS "Generate Script" functionality.

As we all know, SSMS can't import such a big file.

What I tried so far is split the file into 1 GB files, open it with Sublime Text and fix the lines that was cut by using split.

Then I use the cmd line to import the 1 GB files one by one into the SQL Server database.

But this approach takes forever and error prone. Is there an easier way to import a huge SQL file? Again, generating a `.bak` file is not an option because my access is very limited.

Are there tools I can use specifically for this scenario?

For reference, foreign key checks and other constraints are not needed to import this huge file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use a scripting tool to generate a bcp file.  And depending on what your insert staments look like, those could be optimized as well.  For example, you have a 1gb file, are there GO statements after each on?  If so then yes it will be really slow.  You can batch them, like put a GO after every 1k statement.

Comment: If nothing else, I would go with Azure Data Studio instead of SSMS. It is way more stable with large files and I think it has support (maybe via extension) for large imports.

Comment: Can you not run the file as is via sqlcmd?